# Isn't the Jacobi constant just the Lagrangian times 2?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

At [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_integral#Derivation) the Jacobi constant is expressed as:

$$C_J=2\left(\frac{v^2}{2}-U\right)$$

where $U$ is the potential energy and $v$ is velocity.  If kinetic energy $T$ is defined (as it usually is) $T=\frac{v^2}{2}$, then this equation can be rewritten:

$$C_J=2(T-U)$$

which looks awfully like your run of the mill Lagrangian multiplied by 2.  That is:

$$C_J=2L$$

So why does the Jacobi constant get all this special attention and notation as something unique and different, when in fact it is basically just a Lagrangian?

EDIT: Assuming of course a unit mass $m=1$ so that $T=\frac{mv^2}{2}=\frac{v^2}{2}$.

Comment: The kinetic energy is usually given by $T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, so I think what you have written is wrong.

Comment: @Hunter See edit.